# How do I install a pod with a Personal Access Token?

Tags: git, azure-devops, cocoapods

I migrated a CocoaPodSpecs repository from BitBucket to Azure Dev Ops. I am currently trying to install one of the pods, but the issue is that the only way to download files via git lfs is via HTTPS through a [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page). SSH is not available with my organization. I added an example Podfile below.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://[AZURE_LINK]'
use_frameworks!
target 'SAMPLE_APP'  do
   pod 'SAMPLE_POD'
end
```

I have replaced the actual URL `'https://[AZURE_LINK]'` to illustrate the point. Whenever I run `pod install`, it requests a password (which I cannot use). Is there any way to use a PAT instead in this request? How do I configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remedy this by setting my global git config for HTTP headers per URL, similar to what is noted [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1500).

What I used specifically for ADO is:

```
git config --global http.[AZURE_LINK].extraHeader "AUTHORIZATION: Basic [B64_ENCODED_PAT]"
```